# ReceivePortSync is not defined when using js.scrope

Tags: dart

I trying to use the dart.js call googlemap but receive "Breaking on exception: ReferenceError: ReceivePortSync is not defined". Anyone know about this exception?

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:js'; 
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;
import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';

void main() {
   bindMap();
}

void bindMap(){
   js.scoped((){
   final mapOptions = new MapOptions()
    ..zoom = 8
    ..center = new LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
    ..mapTypeId = MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    ;
    final map = new GMap(query("#map_canvas"), mapOptions);
 });
}
```

Comment: Fixed after added   <script src="packages/browser/interop.js"></script> and <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `<script src="packages/browser/interop.js"></script>` in your html file and add [browser package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/browser) in dependencies.

On your code, you can :

- avoid `js.scoped` that is not needed since few versions of [js](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js).
- remove `import 'dart:js';` that is not needed.

Finally you can have a look at [the simple map example](https://github.com/a14n/dart-google-maps/blob/master/example/01-basics/map-simple/) to have an up-to-date example.